# inserting Dropdown values in Database

Tags: jsp

[image]I need to get values from a table in  jsp page and insert it to database. how to capture
this values, please suggest. How to get dropdown list values and corresponding workorderID.
If any other way to achieve this please suggest

my table in data base is work_assigned with 2 columns workorder_id,Technician_id

### myJsp.jsp

```
            <form action="TechAssigned![ ][2]">
           <%
           ArrayList allworkorders=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("ALL_WORK_ORDERS");
           ArrayList allusers=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("ALL_USERS");

            out.println("<td align=\"center\">"+wto.getWorkorderid()+"</td>");

            out.println("<select name=\"technician_assigned\">");
    out.println("<option>Select </option>");
    Iterator eng=alleng.iterator();
    while(eng.hasNext()){
        UserTO uto1=(UserTO)eng.next();
        out.println("<option value=\""+uto1.getUserid()+" "+wto.getWorkorderid()+"\">"+uto1.getFirstname()+" "+uto1.getLastname()+"</option>");

    }
    out.println("</select>");   
           %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Specify some action in your form in jsp:

```
<form action="/yourprocessingurl" method="post">
```

2 Define in web.xml servlet and url mapping for it. This servlet will process your request.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>processingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.packege.ProcessingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>processingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/yourprocessingurl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

3 In servlet get your parameters from request and save to DB using JDBC or other technology.

```
String selectedValue = request.getParameter("technician_assigned");
```